# Reading all file contents into string - Can I have problems passing value of off_t to malloc() (where expect size_t)?

Tags: c, memory-management, file-io, integer-overflow

Can I have problems passing value of `off_t` to `malloc()` (where expect `size_t`)?

I'm reading a file and storing its contents into memory. The file size is obtained by the `st_size` member from `struct stat` after passed to `stat()` function and then passed to `malloc()` where I will do a call to `fread()` passing the memory returned my `malloc()` as `buf` and file size as `nmemb`.

But the question is: if the file size is really a big number that can't be held by a `size_t` what's the behavior of `malloc()` function on 32-bit/64-bit machine: integer overflow and a broken buf (not number of requested bytes was really returned) or `NULL`?

I know that it may really never happens, so bit probably someone use this application into e.g, supercomputer and request a biggest file to my parser... but I really like to understand the maximum possible about the things, even behavior that can never happen.

Answer (score 1):

How big do you expect your file size to be? For moderate to large files (say a few MiB, but under 2 GiB), you won't have a problem. If your file is larger than 2 GiB and you're on a 32-bit system, you'll have all sorts of problems. If your file is larger than 2 GiB but you're on a 64-bit (Unix) machine, the issue will mainly be available physical memory (to avoid thrashing). Consider using `mmap()` regardless.

> But the question is: if the file size is really a big number that can't be held by a size_t what's the behavior of malloc() function on 32-bit/64-bit machine?

If the value in `off_t` is bigger than the range that can be held in `size_t` (perfectly plausible on a 32-bit system; implausible on a 64-bit system other than Windows 64), then `malloc()` will 'work' but will allocate the space needed by the low-order bits of the `off_t` value.  This isn't what you intended.  As a concrete but plausible example: if `off_t` is a 64-bit quantity but `size_t` is a 32-bit quantity, the low order bits of the `off_t` will be used as the size by `malloc()`, ignoring the high order bits.  If the high order bits were all zero, that's not a problem.  If any of the high order bits were set, you're going to be abusing memory that wasn't allocated.

Note that there's nothing `malloc()` can do to detect the problem.  It is given a `size_t` by the compiler because the declaration in `<stdlib.h>` says that's the correct type.  It is all about whether the compiler warns you truncation.  It isn't obliged to warn you about possible problems.

At big file sizes, you have to be aware of the limits of the types you are using, and you have to be extremely careful to make sure you get the result you expect (instead of just the result you asked for, which isn't necessarily the same thing).

Answer (score 1):

**YES** you will have problems. Starting with the fact that by trying to first read the filesize you are essentially prohibiting your users from using e.g. pipes.  Do you absolutely need random access to the data in the file?  If not then try to parse your file in a stream-oriented manner.  If you absolutely need it in memory then you can use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat64) to first validate whether the file size is larger than what can be accommodated by `off_t` (note that `stat` will fail with `errno==EOVERFLOW` if the filesize cannot fit in the `stat` struct) or than what can be accomodated by `size_t` (compare `st_size` to `SIZE_MAX` or `((size_t)-1)`), and bail early if so (your process would not have enough bits in a pointer to address it even if you were to somehow read it into RAM), otheriwse try `malloc` (and check for a `NULL` return value) or, better perhaps, [`mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) (where available) your file.

---

**POST SCRIPTUM**

@R did not like me mentioning `stat64` because it is non-standard (i.e. non-POSIX.)  Technically that is quite correct, though in reality `stat64` is readily available (and documented) on Linux, Solaris, OSX, HP-UX, AIX, QNX, and even in Windows's MSVCRT.  It is *not* available on OpenBSD because on OpenBSD regular `stat` already has [large file support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support).

The conventional (and somewhat more [standard](http://opengroup.org/platform/lfs.html)) way of retrieving the >2GB file size is to build using `_LARGEFILE_SOURCE`, `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE` and `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, which *might* make `stat` behave like `stat64` (you'd still have to ascertain whether `sizeof(off_t) >= 64/8` to know for sure whether you have 8TB support.)

The truth of the matter is that all of the above is, in your case, academic.  You do not need to know the exact file size for that initial check, only if it is in excess of what can be accommodated by the smaller of `off_t` and `size_t`.  I have updated the original answer, top, accordingly.

Comment: Use `stat`, not the nonstandard `stat64`, with a proper programming environment where `off_t` is 64-bit.

Comment: @R.., IIRC what you call "`stat` with a proper programming environment where `off_t` is 64-bit" *is* actually `stat64` on most platforms that I can think of (Linux, Solaris etc., though probably not OpenBSD) with preprocessor sugar (ABI/compatibility *oblige*.) Since the point of the check above is to "do the right thing", as opposed to silently not doing anything because someone forgot to define the right LFS macros at compile time, I went straight for `stat64` -- though yes, you could check `sizeof(off_t) >= 64` instead and warn about activating LFS if supported.

Comment: My point was that you should not be teaching implementation details (like `stat64` or `mmap2`, the latter of which is not even a function name but just the internal syscall name) in place of clean, portable programming practices.